# Why isn't it possible for browser vendors to implement WebPush on iOS?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, apple-push-notifications, progressive-web-apps, web-push

If iOS supports native push notifications, why isn't it possible for Chrome team (and other browsers' vendors) to implement [WebPush](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/)? Are there any technical restrictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because on iOS, Apple has (so far) disabled support for service workers in any browser other than Safari, and has also done the same on WebView.